# Current timestamp as filename in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I want to name new files created by my Java application with the current timestamp.

I need help with this. How do I name the new files created with the current timestamp? Which classes should I include?

Comment: What if multiple files are created at the same time? Is this an [XY problem?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

No need to get too complicated, try this one liner:

```
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'.txt'").format(new Date());
```

Comment: dude, I love one-liners :)  +1

Comment: Nice simple line

Comment: add "seconds" too if not all file will overwrite if they save in within same minute ("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.txt'")

Comment: Update: The terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 9):

try this one

```
String fileSuffix = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current timestamp appended with a file extension in the following way:

```
String fileName = new Date().getTime() + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTime`

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
```

Option 1 : with `yyyyMMddHHmmss`

```
DateTime.now().toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Will give `20190205214430`

Option 2 : `yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss`

```
   DateTime.now().toString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")
```

will give `2019-05-2--21-43-32`

Answer (score 4):

Improving the @`Derek Springer` post with fill length function:

```java
public static String getFileWithDate(String fileName, String fileSaperator, String dateFormat) {
    String FileNamePrefix = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(fileSaperator));
    String FileNameSuffix = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(fileSaperator)+1, fileName.length());
    //System.out.println("File= Prefix~Suffix:"+FileNamePrefix +"~"+FileNameSuffix);
    
    String newFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("'"+FileNamePrefix+"_'"+dateFormat+"'"+fileSaperator+FileNameSuffix+"'").format(new Date());
    System.out.println("New File:"+newFileName);
    return newFileName;
}
```

Using the funciton and its Output:

```java
String fileSaperator = ".", format = "yyyyMMMdd_HHmm";
getFileWithDate("Text1.txt", fileSaperator, format);
getFileWithDate("Text1.doc", fileSaperator, format);
getFileWithDate("Text1.txt.json", fileSaperator, format);
```

Output:

```
Old File:Text1.txt   New File:Text1_2020Nov11_1807.txt
Old File:Text1.doc   New File:Text1_2020Nov11_1807.doc
Old File:Text1.txt.json  New File:Text1.txt_2020Nov11_1807.json
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and whatever classes are required on the I/O side of things (there are many possibilities).

Comment: Question is already answered by aix, but don't forget to ensure that you use only the chars allowed on all OSs you're serving. I mean use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @aix: my application creates new files every 30 mins. Hence i need time+date as the file name. i tried this:
'String pattern = "mm/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat (pattern);
        str = format.format(new Date());'
then i named my file as str.".txt", but it is giving me an error. [Error: 49\20\2011.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)].
Besides, I also need the current time. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` as aix suggested to format the current time into a string.
You should use a format that does not include `/` characters etc. I would suggest something like `yyyyMMddhhmm`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this option

```java
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.txt'", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

A newer alternative using the Java 8 API

```
String filename = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")) + ".txt";
```

Using

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Gives an output like

```
2023-12-20-09-27-17.txt
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is inherently ambiguous as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So it does not meet the need stated in the Question: a timestamp. So your result is ambiguous as well. We have no idea if you mean 9:27 AM in Tokyo, 9:27 AM in Toulouse, or 9:27 AM in Toledo Ohio — all very different moments several hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" ) )
```

> 20231220T192055Z

See [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/egbUy4).

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Avoid the terribly flawed date-time classes seen in the older Answers here. Do not use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

### `java.time.Instant`

To capture the current moment as seen with an offset from the temporal meridian of UTC of zero hours-mintues-seconds, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant now  = Instant.now() ;
```

[Truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) to your desired resolution. I will assume you want whole seconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now().truncateTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

### File systems

Various file systems use various characters as delimiters in their file paths. In Unix including modern macOS file system, a slash. In legacy Mac file system, a colon. In Windows, a backslash.

So we must avoid those characters when producing a file name.

#### “Basic” ISO 8601

One way to avoid those characters is to use the *basic* variation of ISO 8601 formats. The basic variations avoid the use of punctuation marks. The `T` in the middle remains to separate the date portion from the time-of-day portion.

If our date-time value is in UTC (has an offset of zero), we want a `Z` to appear on the end. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”. The formatting code `X` will produce a `Z` if the offset is zero.

Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class to define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" ) ;
```

To be more human readable, we could insert hyphen characters as separators. As far as I know, no file system uses hyphen as a path delimiter. But this custom format is not standard.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ssX" ) ;
```

#### `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

To generate formatted text, we need to convert our `Instant` to the more flexible class `OffsetDateTime`. The `Instant` class is a basic building-block of the *java.time* framework, so it designed simply to represent a moment, with little other functionality.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = now.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Generate text.

```
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> 20231220T192055Z

### File path

Use NIO.2 to create a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) object for your new file. Calling [`Path.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) is one way.

```
Path path = Path.of( "wherever" , "someFolder" , dateTimeString + ".txt" ) ;
```

### Example code

```java
String dateTime =
        OffsetDateTime
                .now ( ZoneOffset.UTC )
                .format ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" ) );
Path path = Path.of ( "/Users/your_username" , dateTime + ".txt" );
try
        (
                BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter ( path ) ;
        )
{
    writer.write ( "At the tone the time will be: " + Instant.now ( ) );
} catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException ( e );
}
```