# What is a suitable name for text File

Tags: android, text, time

Within my application I am saving data from a game to a `.txt file.`

I am having the problem at the minute that the `String` name of the text file is causing the file to be split into two if the game is played over more than a minute.

E.g. if its played over `9.22am` and `9.23am` then two sperate files are created.

How can I create a more suitable file name, that will be unique for each file.

Code relating to name of text file:

```
Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "Maths-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;
```

**Full write to file method:**

```
public void writeToFileEEGPower(String data){


            Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "Maths-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;

            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

            FileOutputStream os;

            try{

                boolean append= true;

                os= new FileOutputStream(file, append);

                String writeMe =data + "\n";


                os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

                os.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you using time in the txt's filename, if you don't want to ?

Comment: Your problem is that you keep re-deriving the file name.  You should probably decide what constitutes a session (rather non-trivial on Android, unless there is a defined "end" of your game), create a filename by whatever method you chose, and then use that same name for the duration of the session.

Comment: Instead of assigning the fileName inside writeToFileEEGPower() method, create a class level variable and assign it inside the constructor.

Comment: @Adrian - yes as a basic mechanism, but Android may keep instances of an Activity class around for hours or days, across apparent user sessions.  So it may be necessary to use some logic tuned to the desired user experience of this particular app to decide when a new session has begun and a new file name should be assigned.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: You should first consider other strategies for generating unique files names like random ones.

You can do it this way:

```
String fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.txt';
```

or

```
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDhhmmss'.txt'").format(new Date().getTime());
```

A way to generate file names randomly is:

```
String name = String.format("%s.txt", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10));
```

Have a look at this related SO questions:

- [Current Timestamp as File name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488559/current-timestamp-as-file-name-in-java)
- [What is the best way to generate a unique and short file name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.  The poster is already accomplishing creating a file with a timestamp as a name, and adding seconds will only make the problem *worse*.

Comment: You are not reading the problem statement in the question.  Random names would be even worse.